# Array Manipulation HackerRank in Python

Tags: python

can anyone post the solution of HackerRank Array Manipulation?

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

I did my best with:

```
def listMax(n, operations):
# Write your code here

l = [0 for i in range(n)]

def doOperation(a,b,k):
    for i in range(a-1,b):
        val = l[i]
        val += k
        l[i] = val

for op in operations:
    a,b,k = op[0],op[1],op[2]
    doOperation(a,b,k)

l.sort()
return l [n-1]
```

...but I was not able to pass the performance tests getting

> time out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution there

https://jugsi.blogspot.com/2019/11/hacker-rank-array-manipulation-in-python.html

```
def listMax(n, operations):
# Write your code here

l = [0 for i in range(n+2)]


def _do(a,b,k):
    l[a] +=k
    l[b+1] -=k

for o in operations:
    a,b,k = o[0],o[1],o[2]
    _do(a,b,k)

c = 0
x_max = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    c +=l[i]
    c_max = max(c,v_max)

return x_max
```

how it works? Using the prefix sum algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

There https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDhf04AJIRs the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for it was:

```py
N, M = map(int, raw_input().split())
arr=[0]*(N+2)
for _m in xrange(0, M):
    a,b,k = map(int, raw_input().split())
    arr[a]+=k
    arr[b+1]-=k
for n in xrange(2, N+1):
    arr[n]+=arr[n-1]
print max(arr)
```

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my approach.

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):

    mat=[]
    r=len(queries)
    row1=[0] * n
    a=b=k=0
    maximum_row=[]
    
    for i in range(r):
        a=queries[i][0]
        b=queries[i][1]
        k=queries[i][2]
    
        row1[a-1:b] = map((k).__add__, row1[a-1:b])
        maximum_row.append(max(row1))
        
return(max(maximum_row))
```